# Wrap two elements in HTML with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code that is generated by php:

```
<div class="fusion-post-content post-content">
   <h2 class="blog-shortcode-post-title"></h2>
   <p class="fusion-single-line-meta"></p>
   <div class="fusion-post-content-container"></div>
</div>
```

I need to wrap two elements by using javascript so the code would look like this:

```
<div class="fusion-post-content post-content">
  <div class="class">
   <h2 class="blog-shortcode-post-title"></h2>
   <p class="fusion-single-line-meta"></p>
  </div>
   <div class="fusion-post-content-container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your attempts.

Comment: Can't you just do this is PHP?

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want. Isn't it better to change the code on server-side??

```js
// Select the first element found
var parent = document.querySelector('.fusion-post-content');
console.log('Old child-length', parent.children.length);
console.log('Old:', parent.innerHTML);

// *You don't need the timeout
setTimeout(function () {
  var h2 = parent.firstElementChild;
  var p = parent.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling;

  // Remove cildren
  parent.removeChild(h2);
  parent.removeChild(p);

  // Insert the new child
  parent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="class"></div>');

  // Insert the other children (old) in the new child
  parent.firstElementChild.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', h2);
  parent.firstElementChild.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', p);
  
  // Gets one less, since we put to children in one (3 - 1 = 2)
  console.log('New child-length', parent.children.length);
  console.log('New:', parent.innerHTML);
}, 500);
```

```html
<div class="fusion-post-content post-content">
  <h2 class="blog-shortcode-post-title"></h2>
  <p class="fusion-single-line-meta"></p>
  <div class="fusion-post-content-container"></div>
</div>
```